# Finding maximum of a function of two variables in a given domain

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the function $$f(r,t)=r^{2n}-2 r^n\cos nt+1$$ where $n $ is an integer .I want to find the maximum value of $f$ over $(r,t) \in  [0,1] \times[0,2 \pi]$ .
As usual  inorder to find the critical points , we equate to  zero the two derivatives  as follows:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=0 \implies 2nr^{2n}-2n r^n \cos nt=  0  
$$ and
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0  \implies 2r^n \sin nt=0$$.This gives us $$ r^n(r^n-\cos nt)=0   \,\text{and}\, r^n \sin nt=0$$. I  think this should give us $r=1$ and $t=\frac{m \pi}{n}$. How should I chose $m.$Are my calculations correct?  Can somebody kindly help?Thank you for your responces in advance.

Comment: Yes,but the constraint here is not given in a way that seems easily  amenable to that method

Comment: Where are you stuck? This seems like a straightforward extrema problem, no? We equate the gradient to $0$ to find critical points and we can pick only those that are inside $[0,1]\times[0,2\pi]$ and then you just need to find which one gives the maximal value when substituted into $f(r,t)$. Is it hard to solve the equations of the gradient equal to $0$ or is there some other problem?

Comment: (And for the edges i.e. $x=0, 0\leq y \leq 2\pi$ and the other 3 edges, you can just substitute one variable to get a single variable function and find its extrema)

Comment: @Snaw,I added the calculations to the question. Could you kindly have a look?

Comment: The derivative with respect to $r$ of $r^{2n}$ is $2nr^{2n-1}$, not $2nr^{2n}$.

Comment: Yes,I multiplied by $r$  throughout

Comment: In the derivative with respect to $r$ it should remain $\cos(nt)$ not $\sin(nt)$

Comment: @Snaw How should I chose m?

Comment: Every $m$ with $\frac {m\pi}n \in [0,2\pi]$ gives a critical point. You don't "choose $m$". You check all of them to figure out which gives the maximum. Fortunately, $\cos m\pi = \pm 1$, so there are only two values to check to find the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve it without calculus.

$$ r^{2n}-2r^n\cos(nt)+1 = r^{2n}-2r^n\cos(nt)+\cos^2(nt)+\sin^2(nt) \\=(r^n-\cos (nt))^2+\sin^2(nt)$$

both terms are non-negative, inside first term, since always $r^n\ge 0$, this equation reaches it's maximum when $\cos (nt)$ reaches it's negative minimum, i.e. $nt=(2k-1)\pi \Rightarrow t=\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{n}$. Since we want $t \in [0,2\pi]$, we choose $k=1$. It is equivalent to $m=1$ in your solution. The domain of the function restricts the answer, otherwise there is no restriction. That's why $r=1$ is optimal.

Comment: when we input n=20 in mathematica and use the code

Comment: n = 20; f[r_, t_] = r^(2 n) - 2 r^n Cos[n*t] + 1; Maximize[{f[r, t], 0 <= r <= 1, 0 <= t <= 2 Pi}, {r, t}]....we get $t=3 \pi/20$ and not $t=\pi/20 $.Also,it gives the max value as 4

Comment: Yes you are in fact correct, I mistook $(2k-1)\pi$ with $k\pi$, we need odd multiples to get $\cos nt =-1$ and not $\cos nt =1$. I eddited the solution and thanks!